# When and how does a conscious character recover from wounds?

Tags: healing, traveller

In Traveller (GDW: 1981 printing) if I sustain a wound in combat but am conscious at the end of combat, how and when do those wounds recover? P.34 of "Characters and Combat" details how and when *unconscious* characters recover from wounds, but it says nothing about a character who never becomes unconscious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone pointed me to [these errata](http://dmckinne.winterwar.org/pdfs/ConsolidatedCTErrata.pdf), which includes the following:

> Page 34,  Wounding and Death, fourth paragraph  (clarification  and  addition):
>   Characters  who  are  wounded when  a  combat  ends  but  never  go  unconscious  (because  no  characteristic  ever  is  reduced  to  zero)  have  their **characteristics reset to halfway between the wounded and full strength** values (round fractional characteristics down).
>
> The individual is considered to have  sustained  minor  wounds.  For  example,  a  character  with  a  strength  of  8  who  is wounded  to  a  strength  of  4  (and  remains  conscious  throughout  the  combat) becomes  strength  6  at  the  end  of  the 
>   combat  and  remains  so  until  recovered.  **A  return  to  full  strength  for  the  character  requires  medical  attention  (30 minutes with a medical kit and an individual with at least medical-1 skill) or three days of rest.**
>
> [emphasis added]

Answer (score 3):

Per the rules as written, minor wounds do NOT recover any points at all until treated. So, until treated, or 3 days have passed, no recovery happens at all; once either has happened, they're returned to full.

> ## Minor Wounds
>
> Any wound points applied to a
> character which do not reduce more
> than one physical characteristic to zero
> are considered minor wounds. The
> character is treated as having the reduced
> characteristics until medical care
> or recovery has taken place. (Starter Traveller Book 2, p9)

and

> **Minor Wounds:** Minor wounds require
> a medical kit, skill of medical-I,
> and thirty minutes. Without medical
> care, recovery requires three days rest. (ibid.)

Note that the Little Black Books are all essentially CT 2.0; The Traveller Book is 2.1, and the Starter Traveller boxed set is 2.2. Both TTB and ST agree that minor wounds don't heal any loss until either treated or naturally healed.

That said, many consider the minor wounds to be moved to the midway point a the same point as unconsciousness - which would be 10 minutes.

> ## Unconsciousness
>
> One characteristic reduced to zero
> results in unconsciousness for ten
> minutes. Upon recovery of consciousness,
> any wounded characteristics are
> placed midway between their wounded
> and full levels; round fractions down. (ibid.)

Comment: The errata is a back-port from MegaTraveller. If you have the errata from Don McKinney, it's the official one. But that's not Rules as Written.